# How to infer schema when readying parquet in s3 using pyspark

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, parquet

when using `spark.read.parquet` to read the parquet files saved in s3, it automatically changed some of the datatypes. e.g. string to int.

How can I disable this and persist original data type for all columns when reading.

for reading csv there's an option `inferSchema='false'`. Is there an equivalent for reading parquet? I can't find it anywhere in the documentation.

Comment: The parquet file is not human readable and it maintains its schema inside the file itself. If you try to read it, Spark refers to the parquet footer to get the file schema.

Comment: Please make sure the column datatype when you write it, if that is out of your scope transform the column using transformations or use explicit schema.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can try to read with explicit schema:

```
CustomSchema = StructType([
    StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("string_value", StringType(), True)
])

df = spark.read.schema(CustomSchema).parquet("root/my_path)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not very convenient if we have a few dozen of dataframes in one process.